# Vector spaces for the irreducible representations of the Lorentz Group

Tags: special-relativity, group-theory, representation-theory, lorentz-symmetry, group-representations

EDIT:  *The vector space for the $(\frac{1}{2},0)$ Representation is $\mathbb{C}^2$ as mentioned by Qmechanic in the comments to his answer below! The vector spaces for the other representations remain unanswered.*

The definition of a representation is a map (a homomorphism) to the space of linear operators over a vector space. My question is: What are the corresponding vector spaces for the

- $(0,0)$ Representation
- $(\frac{1}{2},0)$ Representation
- $(0,\frac{1}{2})$ Representation
- $(\frac{1}{2},0) \oplus (0,\frac{1}{2}) $ Representation
- $(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})$ Representation
- infinite dimensional Representation?

Answer (score 14):

I) [Representation theory for the double cover $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ of the restricted$^1$ Lorentz group $SO^+(1,3;\mathbb{R})$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_theory_of_the_Lorentz_group) is a fairly broad subject covered in many textbooks, see e.g. Ref. 1 for further information.

An [irreducible representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irreducible_representation)$^2$

$$ (j_L,j_R)~=~j_L\otimes_{\mathbb{C}} j_R, \qquad 
j_L, j_R~\in~ \frac{1}{2}\mathbb{N}_0,\tag{1}$$

is a [tensor product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product) of $V=V_L\otimes_{\mathbb{C}} V_R$ of two complex vector spaces $V_L$ and $V_R$, of complex dimension $2j_L+1$ and $2j_R+1$, respectively. The tensor product $V$ is again a complex vector space and has complex dimension $(2j_L+1)(2j_R+1)$. See also [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/41424/2451) Phys.SE post.

*Examples:*

1. $(j_L,j_R)=(0,0)$. This is the [trivial/singlet representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trivial_representation). Then the vector-space is $V\cong\mathbb{C}$. Note that the trivial representation $(0,0)$ is the [multiplicative identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_%28mathematics%29) for the tensor product $\otimes_{\mathbb{C}}$, i.e.

$$\forall V:~~(0,0)\otimes_{\mathbb{C}}V~\cong~ V~\cong~ V\otimes_{\mathbb{C}}(0,0).\tag{2}$$

2. $(j_L,j_R)=(\frac{1}{2},0)$. This is known as the left-handed Weyl-spinor representation. Then the vector-space is $V\cong\mathbb{C}^2$. It is the [fundamental/defining representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_representation) of $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$.
3. $(j_L,j_R)=(0,\frac{1}{2})$. This is known as the right-handed Weyl-spinor representation. It is the [complex conjugate representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_conjugate_representation) of the left-handed Weyl-spinor representation.
4. $(j_L,j_R)=(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})$. This is isomorphic to the vector representation of the Lorentz group.
5. The [Dirac-spinor representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_spinor) $(\frac{1}{2},0) \oplus (0,\frac{1}{2})$ is a direct sum of the left- and right-handed Weyl-spinor representation.

An irreducible representation (1) can be written with the help of the  [symmetric tensor product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_tensor) $\odot$ of the left-handed and right-handed Weyl-spinor representation

$$(j_L,j_R)~=~(\frac{1}{2},0)^{\odot 2j_L} \otimes (0,\frac{1}{2})^{\odot 2j_R}$$
$$~:=~\underbrace{\left\{(\frac{1}{2},0)\odot\ldots\odot(\frac{1}{2},0)\right\}}_{2j_L\text{ symmetrized factors}} \otimes \underbrace{\left\{(0,\frac{1}{2})\odot\ldots\odot(0,\frac{1}{2})\right\}}_{2j_R\text{ symmetrized factors}} .\tag{3} $$

Here $\otimes$ denotes the standard (un-symmetrized) [tensor product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product).

II) *Complexification.* The restricted Lorentz group $SO^+(1,3;\mathbb{R})$ is obviously a subgroup of the complexified$^2$ Lorentz group $SO(1,3;\mathbb{C})$. One can show that the double cover of the complexified Lorentz group $SO(1,3;\mathbb{C})$ is isomorphic to the [direct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_product) or [Cartesian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) product group

$$ G~=~SL(2,\mathbb{C})_L\times SL(2,\mathbb{C})_R,\tag{4}$$

cf. e.g. Ref. 1 and [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/28505/2451) Phys.SE post.

In more detail, the irreducible representation (1) for $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ lifts to an irreducible representation

$$ \rho~=~\rho_L\otimes \rho_R:G\to GL(V,\mathbb{C})\tag{5}$$

for the product Lie group (4) given as

$$ \rho(g_L,g_R)(\sum_iv^i_L\otimes v^i_R)~=~\sum_i\rho_L(g_L)v^i_L\otimes\rho_R(g_R)v^i_R ,\tag{6}$$

where both

$$ \rho_{L/R}:SL(2,\mathbb{C})\to GL(V_{L/R},\mathbb{C})\tag{7}$$

are irreducible representations of $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ of complex dimensions $2j_{L/R}+1$.

References:

1. I.L. Buchbinder and S.M. Kuzenko, *Ideas and Methods of Supersymmetry and Supergravity - Or a Walk Through Superspace,* 1998; Chapter 1.

--

$^1$ Let us here for simplicity consider the [restricted Lorentz group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_group#The_restricted_Lorentz_group) $SO^+(1,3;\mathbb{R})$ rather than the [Lorentz group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_group) $O(1,3;\mathbb{R})$. To allow for spinor representations, we need to go to the double cover $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$.

$^2$ We can [w.l.o.g.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Without_loss_of_generality) assume that a representation over a real vector space is complexified to a complex vector space.

$^3$ It turns out that relativistic physical theories often have pertinent complex analytic properties. See also [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/410952/2451) related Phys.SE.

Comment: Regarding 3. — by isomorphic to the vector rep, do you mean the complexificiation of the vector rep? Otherwise I don't see how it could be the case that $\mathbb{C}^2\otimes\mathbb{C}^2 \cong \mathbb{R^4}$

Comment: $\uparrow$ Yes.

Answer (score 3):

---

**(A)**

(0,0) acts on a trivial space $\mathbb{C}. $

---

**(B)**

$(\frac{1}{2},0)$  acts on a vector space which is same as a spin space $( \alpha|\uparrow \rangle +\beta | \downarrow\rangle) $ , ignoring the meaning of spin up and down now. This space is just $\mathbb{C}^2 $ up to a normalization constraint $|\alpha|^2+|\beta|^2=1.$

---

**(C)**

$(0,\frac{1}{2})$ acts on a vector space, which has the same structure as $(\frac{1}{2},0)$'s space, but may have different meaning, I write it as $( \gamma|\Uparrow \rangle +\delta | \Downarrow\rangle). $

---

**(D)**

$(\frac{1}{2},0) \oplus (0,\frac{1}{2}) $ acts on $(\alpha|\uparrow \rangle +\beta | \downarrow\rangle) \oplus (\gamma|\Uparrow\rangle +\delta | \Downarrow\rangle)=( \alpha|\uparrow\rangle +\beta |\downarrow\rangle + \gamma|\Uparrow\rangle +\delta | \Downarrow\rangle). $

---

**(E)**

$(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}) $  acts on $(\alpha|\uparrow\rangle +\beta | \downarrow\rangle)\otimes (\gamma|\Uparrow\rangle +\delta | \Downarrow\rangle  )=(a|A\rangle + b|B\rangle +c|C\rangle +d|D\rangle).$

$|\alpha|^2+|\beta|^2=1$ and $|\gamma|^2+|\delta|^2=1$ may not hold, it becomes one expression for $a \ b \ c \ d.$

---

**(F)**

infinite basis, adding extra momentum to **(B)** for example:

$(\alpha_1|\uparrow,p_1\rangle +\beta_1 | \downarrow,p_1\rangle)\oplus( \alpha_2|\uparrow,p_2\rangle +\beta_2 | \downarrow,p_2\rangle)\oplus( \alpha_3|\uparrow,p_3 \rangle +\beta_3 | \downarrow,p_3\rangle)\oplus...$

I am using $\oplus$, since $\langle s_1,p_i|s_2,p_j\rangle =\delta_{ij} \langle s_1 |s_2\rangle .$

Therefore the space is:

$$(\sum_{s=1,2} \sum_{p} a_{s,p} |s,p\rangle)$$ with normalization constraint $\sum_{s=1,2} \sum_{ p} |a_{s,p}|^2=1.$

similarly, you can add extra momentum to **(A) (C) (D) (E)**, to realize their infinite versions.

for **(A)**'s infinite version, that vector space is just $ \{ |p\rangle \} $ itself.

Comment: (D) is not an irreducible representation, is it?

Comment: @gented . No, the bispinor rep is reducible, cf. Dirac spinors.