# What does it mean to take the tensor product of two reps of the Lorentz group?

Tags: special-relativity, group-theory, representation-theory, group-representations, spinors

If I reduce the Lorentz group to the representation $\mathfrak{su}(2)\oplus \mathfrak{su}(2)$, I can write left and right-handed Weyl spinors respectively as $\left( \frac{1}{2},0 \right)$ and $\left(0, \frac{1}{2} \right)$. I can get a Dirac spinor by summing them, i.e. $\left( \frac{1}{2},0 \right) \oplus \left(0, \frac{1}{2} \right)$.

In my lecture notes, it is said that one can obtain *higher representations* by taking the tensor product. As an example, my prof gives $\left( \frac{1}{2},0 \right) \otimes \left(0, \frac{1}{2} \right) = \left(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2} \right)$, and he says that this corresponds to spin $1$ with $4$ components. I don't really understand what are the numbers on the right-hand side, and how I can relate this object to spin $1$. What does this notation mean, and how does the calculation work?

Comment: possible dup.? https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/192349/84967

Comment: First, [due diligence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_theory_of_the_Lorentz_group).

Comment: @CosmasZachos Yes, I was there of course, but I couldn't find a tensor product similar to what I wrote in the OP. Or did I miss it?

Comment: The Kronecker product  $1/2 \otimes 0 =1/2$ you already know from addition of spins: adding spin 1/2 to spin 0, i.e. combination of a doublet  with a singlet yields a doublet. This happens to both direct sum subspaces. Try a matrix example.

Comment: @CosmasZachos Thanks for your comment. Let's see if I understand this right: then the product $\left(1/2, 0 \right) \otimes \left(1/2 , 0 \right)$ would be equal to $(0,0) \oplus (1,0)$? That is, when the spins are either antiparallel or parallel?

Comment: Correct! They are merely notional spins for the two SU(2)s, but that's the idea. The (m,n) rep is detailed in [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_theory_of_the_Lorentz_group#The_(m,_n)-representations_of_so(3;_1)).

Comment: @CosmasZachos I see, thanks a lot! And sorry for the duplicate.

Comment: Might find [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/147987/does-the-bf13-representation-of-su2-also-represent-su2-times-su2) useful.