# $(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})$ and $(\frac{1}{2},0)\bigoplus (0,\frac{1}{2})$

Tags: special-relativity, group-theory, lie-algebra, representation-theory, spinors

I am confused about the notation.

What's the differences between $(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})$ and $(\frac{1}{2},0)\bigoplus  (0,\frac{1}{2})$, or maybe $(\frac{1}{2},0)\bigoplus  (\frac{1}{2},0)$ ?

(1) $so(1,3)=su(2) \bigoplus su(2)$ has different representations, I don't understand why  $(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})$ is irreducible, since we already have direct sum  $\bigoplus$ between two $su(2)$, and direct sum usually means reducible.

The Schwartz book (page 163) says $(\frac{n}{2},\frac{n}{2})$ These are each irreducible representations of the Lorentz algebra, but reducible representations of the $su(2)$ subalgebra corresponding to spin.

(2) The group elements are acting on some space, then $\bigoplus$ means the direct sum of these spaces, like $(\frac{1}{2},0)\bigoplus  (0,\frac{1}{2})$. Then what does $(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})$ means, a direction product $(\frac{1}{2},0)\bigotimes  (0,\frac{1}{2})$ ?

Comment: One should distinguish between a Lie algebra and a Lie group. A direct sum of Lie algebras corresponds to a direct product of Lie groups.

Comment: This question (v3) is explained in  http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/149455/2451 and links therein. See also http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/28505/2451