# General definition of an $n$-rank spinor

Tags: special-relativity, tensor-calculus, definition, representation-theory, spinors

I have been looking around for a formal (and easy to comprehend) definition of a general $n$-rank spinor. I have had no luck trying to find such a definition, or any definition for that matter.

So my question is; how would we in general define a $n$-rank spinor and given a 'thing' $\psi$ how could I test whether it was or was not a spinor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An $n$-rank [spinor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spinor) in physics usually means a tensor product of $n$ left- and/or right-handed [Weyl spinors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl_equation). Equivalently, it is the total number of dotted and undotted indices on the spinor.

So e.g. in 3+1D, the [irreducible representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irreducible_representation)
$$(j_L,j_R), \qquad 
j_L, j_R~\in~ \frac{1}{2}\mathbb{N}_0,$$
[of the double cover $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ for the restricted Lorentz group $SO^+(1,3;\mathbb{R})$] is a spinor of rank $n=2j_L+2j_R$. See also [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/149455/2451) Phys.SE post.