# How to contract spinor indices?

Tags: special-relativity, tensor-calculus, vectors, representation-theory, spinors

In normal vector representation, vectors can be contracted as follows:
$$v^\mu v_\mu$$

with one covariant and one contravariant index. But in spinor representation, there are 4 possible type of indices:

$$\psi^{a} $$ $$ \psi^{\dot{a}} $$ $$ \psi_a $$ $$ \psi_{\dot{a}}$$

How do I contract them?

Also, a vector is a rank-2 spinor as the following: $v^{a \dot{b}}$, so is a covariant vector like this: $u_{\dot{a}b}$? What about $w^{a}_{\dot{b}}$ and other countless ways I can construct a rank-2 spinor?

Answer (score 2):

1. Undotted upper and lower indices can be contracted. Undotted indices are raised and lowered with the [Levi-Civita symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol)/tensor $\epsilon_{ab}$.
2. Dotted indices work similarly. Dotted indices are raised and lowered with $\epsilon_{\dot{a}\dot{b}}$.
3. For more information, see e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/28505/2451) & [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/149455/2451) Phys.SE posts.

Comment: Hmm. So if I have a vector that can be represented by 2 spinors: $v^{a\dot{b}}$, it transforms like this: $N_a^c v^{a\dot{b}} N_{\dot{b}}^{\dot{d}}=N_a^c \psi^{a}\psi^{\dot{b}} N_{\dot{b}}^{\dot{d}}=\psi ' ^{c} \psi ' ^ {\dot{d}} = v ' ^ {c \dot{d}}$