# Sym$^2\mathbb{C}^2$ as the unique 3-dimensional irrep of $\operatorname{SU}(2)$

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, lie-algebra

In this script ([Link](https://math.ucr.edu/%7Ehuerta/guts/node4.html)) regarding GUTs it is stated that the unique 3-dimensional complex representation of $\operatorname{SU}(2)$ up to isomorphism is given by Sym$^2\mathbb{C}^2$, the symmetric tensors of rank 2. I was wondering however whether this is indeed true. The author asserts that this representation can also be understood as the Adjoint representation on $\mathbb{C} \otimes \mathfrak{su}(2) \simeq \mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})$. The adjoint representation of $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})$ is however the special linear tensors of rank 2 and not just the symmetric tensors of rank 2. Am I missing something or is the statement wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If $$V_L~\cong~\mathbb{C}^2\tag{1}$$ denotes the fundamental/defining/left Weyl/spin-$(\frac{1}{2},0)$  representation of the Lie group $\operatorname{SL}(2,\mathbb{C})$, then
$$\begin{align}
\{M\in{\rm Mat}_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{C}) \mid M^t=M\}
~\cong~&
{\rm Sym}^2V_L\cr 
~\cong~& \mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})\cr
~\cong~&\{M\in{\rm Mat}_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{C}) \mid {\rm tr}M=0\}\cr
~\cong~&\mathfrak{su}(2)\otimes \mathbb{C}
\end{align}\tag{2}$$
is the adjoint/spin-$(1,0)$ representation, cf. e.g [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/149455/2451) Phys.SE post.

Comment: I understand that this should yield the spin-(1,0) representation. The source of my confusion was regarding the isomorphism between Sym$^2V_L$ and $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C}$. Are they only isomorphic as complex linear spaces? I'd assume there is no isomorphism between $Sym^2V_L$ and $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})$ represented as the symmetric matrices and as traceless matrices such that it is invariant under the action of some matrix from SL(2,$\mathbb{C}$) in the fundamental representation. I hope this clarifies my point of confusion.

Comment: They are [equivalent representations](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Equivalence_of_linear_representations).

Comment: Thanks, I only thought about the vector space isomorphism.