# SUSY Algebra Anti-commutation Relation

Tags: special-relativity, representation-theory, supersymmetry, lie-algebra, superalgebra

I am trying to understand one of the anti-commutation relations of SUSY algebra. The lecture notes "Supersymmetry and Extra Dimensions" ([PDF](https://www.physics.uci.edu/%7Etanedo/files/notes/SUSYXD.pdf)) taken by [Flip Tanedo](https://www.physics.uci.edu/%7Etanedo/docs.html), says on p.29, due to the index structure of the generators inside the brackets, the most general form of the anticommutator is
$$\{Q_\alpha,Q^\beta\}=k(\sigma^{\mu\nu})_\alpha{}^{\beta}\ M_{\mu\nu}\tag{3.25}$$ where $k$ is some constant.

I want to know how the right-hand side is coming, I can't understand how the right-hand side is having such form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The anticommutator on the LHS of eq. (3.25) belongs to the left-handed representation $(1,0)$ (of the double cover) of the [restricted Lorentz group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_group) in 3+1D, so the (graded) Lie algebra generators on the RHS must also belong to the same representation. This implies that the RHS must be a left-handed linear combination of the angular momentum generators $M_{\mu\nu}$. Recall that the angular momentum generators $M_{\mu\nu}$ belongs to  the [reducible representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irreducible_representation) $(1,0)\oplus(0,1)$ [as complex vector spaces], cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/767162/2451) Phys.SE post.
2. Whatever Tanedo means with the coefficient on the RHS of eq. (3.25), the main point is that they have to be zero, since the LHS commutes with $P_{\lambda}$ while the RHS doesn't always.

Comment: Thank you very much, I understand the LHS is (1,0) representation, so it should be the same for the RHS as well. I want to know how $M^{\mu\nu}$ is having (1,0) representation.

Comment: That is the topic of the linked post.

Comment: I am a beginner to the subject and I am having difficulties grasping the abstractness of all the representations, so if you could explain how exactly angular momentum generators are (1,0) representations, I would be grateful. I thought $M_{\mu\nu}$ was an antisymmetric tensor and was having $(1,0)\oplus(0,1)$ represntation.

Comment: I updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you @Qmechanic