# Deriving the $(1/2,1/2) $ representation of the Lorentz Group as in Schwichtenberg

Tags: special-relativity, group-theory, representation-theory

I'm currently studying Jakob Schwichtenberg's "Physics from Symmetry" where on subsection 3.7.8 he proves that the $(1/2,1/2)$ representation of the Lorentz Group corresponds to 4-vectors.

I have a few questions as to why we can do a few of the things he does. For context, this method heavily uses Van der Waerden notation (dot vs undotted indices), which is introduced before getting the 4-vector representation:

It is clear that the representation is 4 dimensional. He chooses to study 2x2 complex matrices. Specifically, it is clear why general matrices would not be an irreducible representation, so we pick Hermitian matrices (which have 4 free parameters, exactly what we want). Let $v$ be the object that's being acted on by the representation.

My questions have to do with the following portion of the text: (page 81)

[image]

Can we add a lower undotted index and an upper doted index into $v$ just because we have the $(1/2,1/2)$ representation? As in, we know beforehand that $(1/2,0)$ corresponds to lower undotted and $(0,1/2)$ corresponds to upper undotted. But I don't see how this is an argument to simply put the lower undotted index and an the upper doted index into $v$.

I understand that we have to copies of $\mathfrak{s}\mathfrak{u}2$, and that they are independent of each other, and that
\begin{equation}
 \left( \frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2} \right) = \left( \frac{1}{2},0 \right) \otimes  \left( 0,\frac{1}{2} \tag{1}\right) 
\end{equation}
But I'm unsure what Eq. 1 really implies/means.

Furthermore, why can't we use the Pauli matrices:

[image]

If we have the lower undotted and the upper dotted index?

Comment: Crossposted to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4729582/11127

Answer (score 1):

The main points are as follows:

1. Ref. 1 defines the left-handed $(\frac{1}{2},0)$ Weyl spinor $\chi_{L,a}$ with a lower undotted index in eq. (3.196) and the right-handed $(0,\frac{1}{2})$ Weyl spinor $\chi_R^{\dot{a}}$ with upper dotted index in eq. (3.197).
2. If we lower the dotted index $\chi_{R,\dot{a}}=\epsilon_{\dot{a}\dot{b}}\chi_R^{\dot{b}}$, then we get an [equivalent representation](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Equivalent_representations) that is the [complex conjugate representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_conjugate_representation) of the left-handed Weyl spinor $\chi_{L,a}$, cf. eqs. (3.199) & (3.205).
3. The left-handed Weyl spinor is the fundamental/defining representation $\chi\mapsto g\chi$ of $g\in G:=SL(2,\mathbb{C})$, cf. eq. (3.209).
4. $(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})\cong (\frac{1}{2},0)\otimes (0,\frac{1}{2})$, cf e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/149455/2451) related Phys/SE post.
5. The vector space for the $(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})$ representation is the set $u(2)$ of Hermitian $2\times 2$ matrices, which is the real linear span of the 3 Pauli matrices (3.80) and the identity matrix, cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/28505/2451) related Phys.SE post.
6. There is a [group action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action) $\rho: SL(2,\mathbb{C})\times u(2) \to u(2)$ of the $(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})$ representation given by
   $$g\quad \mapsto\quad\rho(g)v~:= ~gv g^{\dagger},
   \qquad g\in SL(2,\mathbb{C}),\qquad v~\in~ u(2),$$
   which precisely corresponds to the left-handed Weyl representation times its complex conjugate representation if $v_{a\dot{b}}$ has lower indices. (The complex conjugate $\bar{g}$ turns into a Hermitian conjugate $g^{\dagger}$ since acting from right transposes the matrix.)

References:

1. J. Schwichtenberg, *Physics from Symmetry,* 2nd edition, 2018.

Comment: I don't see how these points answer my questions...

Comment: I updated the answer.

Comment: Do you have proof or a resource as to why $(1/2,1/2)=(1/2,0)\otimes (0,1/2)$. Or maybe just a motivation? I can't seem to connect the idea of building representations through tensor products and this representation in particular. I appreciate your help!

Comment: I updated the answer.