# Tensor Product of Left Handed Spinor and Right Handed Spinor representations of the group $SU(2)_L \times SU(2)_R$

Tags: angular-momentum, quantum-spin, group-theory, representation-theory, spinors

From quantum mechanics, we know that the tensor product of two spin-half representations would give us spin-1, and spin-0 reps, i.e,
$$(1/2,0)\otimes(1/2,0)\cong(1,0)\oplus(0,0)$$
I want to know what happens in case $(1/2,0)\otimes(0,1/2)$.

(I have seen in some places that $(1/2,0)\otimes(0,1/2)$ is equivalent to $(1/2 , 1/2)$, but I just don't understand how... )

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/149455/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Ah thank you for referring to the mentioned link... apart from the reference which you mentioned in the mentioned answer, can you suggest where I can read the required representation theory for SUSY.... @Qmechanic

Comment: “*equivalent to $(1/2,1,2)$*” Do you mean $(1/2, 1/2)$?

Comment: @Ghoster yes (1/2, 1/2)