# Group notation $\otimes$ and $\oplus$ used for representations of quarks and mesons

Tags: group-theory, group-representations, tensor-calculus, notation, representation-theory

I've been trying to figure out this statement from the [PDG quark model summary](http://pdg.lbl.gov/2013/reviews/rpp2012-rev-quark-model.pdf) (PDF).

> Following $\mathrm{SU}(3)$, the nine possible $q\bar{q}′$ combinations containing the light $u$, $d$, and $s$ quarks are grouped into an octet and a singlet of light quark mesons:
>
> $\mathbf{3} \otimes \mathbf{\bar{3}} = \mathbf{8} \oplus \mathbf{1}$

This looks like some very nice notation that comes up now and then, but unfortunately I don't have any idea what it's called and the introductory group theory material I've skimmed doesn't explain it. In particular I'm trying to figure out what the $\otimes$ and $\oplus$ mean.

Obviously this is a simple question to answer with Google, but that's a bit hard without knowing what this is called. What do I have to google to find out more about this?

Comment: wikipedia doesn't use this notation to explain SU(2) or group representation theory, any idea who would?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/41424/2451 and links therein.

Comment: @Shep A lot of graduate physics texts, and Lie group/representation theory texts.

Comment: Something useful to keep in mind: when mathematicians say "introductory group theory" they are thinking of stuff like the Sylow theorems. When physicists say "group theory" they really mean representation theory or module theory or linear algebra -- basically most of introductory abstract algebra *except* group theory proper.

Comment: @Shep So, I had a look around, and Wikipedia does use this notation, see for example http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_Unified_Theory, in the $SU(5)$ section.

Answer (score 12):

In physicist jargon, we talk about [group representations](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/17099243#17099243) of $\mathrm{SU}(2)$ and $\mathrm{SU}(3)$ by denoting an *irreducible* representation whose representation vector space has dimension $N$ by $\mathbf{N}$.

Hence, the statement $\mathbf{3} \otimes \bar{\mathbf{3}} = \mathbf{1} \oplus \mathbf{8}$ is the statement that the [tensor product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product) of the three-dimensional representation of $\mathrm{SU}(3)$ (also called its fundamental representation, as it is the smallest non-trivial one) and its conjugate representation decomposes as the [direct sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_sum) of the eight-dimensional (the *adjoint representation*) and the *trivial* representation.

The notation works for $\mathrm{SU}(3)$ because there are only two [irreducible representations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irreducible_representation) with a given dimension, and they are conjugates of each other, so $\mathbf{N}$ and $\bar{\mathbf{N}}$ are sufficient to denote all possible (finite-dimensional) representations