# What do the symbols $⊕$ and $⊗$ mean?

Tags: terminology, group-theory, notation, group-representations

Please have a look at [this presentation on Young tableaux](https://particle.phys.uvic.ca/~lefebvre/courses/phys506B/2005/Young_Tableaux.pdf),

> [image]

I'm trying to understand the signs I mention there - what do the $\otimes$ and $\oplus$ symbols mean?

Comment: Direct product and direct sum

Comment: If you want to typeset a symbol in [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) but you don't know the command, use [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) to identify it.

Comment: Related: [What does "the ${\bf N}$ of a group" mean?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/41424/).

Comment: Related $SU(3)$ post: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/10403/2451 and links therein; especially the answer http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/14586/2451 .

Answer (score 2):

The symbols $\oplus$ and $\otimes$ are generally used to denote direct sums and direct products, with the precise details depending on the context (i.e. depending on whether you're talking about groups or vector spaces or some other algebraic structure).

In the [group-representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_theory) context embodied by these Young tableaux, the $\oplus$ symbol denotes the [direct sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_sum) of the vector spaces of two representations, and the $\otimes$ symbol denotes their [tensor product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product), with both implicitly conferring a group representation to the resulting vector space (i.e. a mapping $g:G\to U\oplus V$ or $g:G\to U\otimes V$) given by the [direct sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_sum#Direct_sum_of_group_representations) and [tensor product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_theory_of_finite_groups#Tensor_product_of_representations), respectively, of the individual factors' representations.